# HostListener is not firing at reset event

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I'm using a HostListener in a AbstractControl (input element) to try to listen the reset event. But when I reset the form that is a parent of this input element, the HostListener don't fire.

The code and the error you can see in:
http://plnkr.co/edit/BYX8RsqUgY4FHvjhyN1X?p=preview

When you submit this, the right result is to reset the input element and clearing the success class, but it is not working. The `@HostListener('reset')` in the ngModel is not being fired.

Debugging you can see that the reset event is fired by the browser to the input element, but the angular/javascript is not catching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answered at github.com:
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/16847

```js
 @HostListener('ngModelChange', ['$event']) onModelChange(value: any) {
    if (!value) {
      console.log("reset?")
      // empty: probably reset, or just erased
      this.handleClasses();
    }
  }
```